# Mutate string from an extension

Tags: kotlin

I was trying to port a Swift script to Kotlin but it's not working as expected, what the code does is to consume a string while the condition is true (need it for a parser). In Swift it works as expected but in Kotlin it doesn't (I just started with Kotlin a month ago so maybe I'm missing something).

**Swift**

```
extension String {
    @discardableResult public mutating func consumeWhile(test: (String) -> Bool) -> String {
        var chars = [Character](self.characters)
        var result = ""

        while chars.count > 0 && test(String(chars[0])) {
            result.append(chars.remove(at: 0))
        }

        self = String(chars)

        return result
    }
}
```

**Kotlin**

```
fun String.consumeWhile(test: (String) -> Boolean): String {
    if (isEmpty()) return ""

    val chars = toCharArray().toMutableList()
    var result = ""
    var i = -1

    while (chars.isNotEmpty() && test(chars.first().toString())) {
        result += chars.removeAt(0)
        ++i
    }

    removeRange(0..i)

    return result
}
```

So the basic usage will look like

```
val myString = "--Test" // IntelliJ suggests change var to val
val consumedString = myString.consumeWhile{ it != "-" }
println("result: $myString consumedString: $consumedString") 
// expected: "result: Test consumedString: --"
// but got: "result: --Test consumedString: --"
```

**Edit:** Thanks for all the answers, don't know if will be possible to do like I want because as mentioned string are immutable in Kotlin/Java (just using the same string).

I forgot to mention that I need the consumed string, basically b/c I'm doing a parser so I need to store the consumed chars and the mutated string. I will leave open this question but I ended up creating a class that implements only a few String class methods.

```
class Line(var string: String) {
    val length: Int
        get() = string.length

    fun consumeWhile(test: (String) -> Boolean): String {
        if (string.isEmpty()) return ""

        val chars = string.toCharArray().toMutableList()
        var result = ""

        while (chars.isNotEmpty() && test(chars.first().toString())) {
            result += chars.removeAt(0)
        }

        string = chars.joinToString("")

        return result
    }

    fun isNullOrEmpty(): Boolean {
        return string.isNullOrEmpty()
    }

    fun isNotEmpty(): Boolean {
        return string.isNotEmpty()
    }

    private fun removeRange(range: IntRange) {
        string = string.removeRange(range)
    }

    operator fun get(i: Int): Char {
        return string[i]
    }
}
```

**Usage example**

```
val line = Line(string)

if (line.isNotEmpty() && line[0].toString() == "(") {
    line.consumeWhile { it == "(" }
    while (line.isNotEmpty() && line[0].toString() != ")") {
        line.consumeWhile { it == " " }
        val key = line.consumeWhile { it != "=" }
        line.consumeWhile { it == "\"" || it == "=" }
        val value = line.consumeWhile { it != "\"" }
        line.consumeWhile { it == "\"" }

        attributes[key] = value
    }

    line.consumeWhile { it == ")" }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up creating a class that implements only a few String class methods.

```
class Line(var string: String) {
    val length: Int
        get() = string.length

    fun consumeWhile(test: (String) -> Boolean): String {
        if (string.isEmpty()) return ""

        val chars = string.toCharArray().toMutableList()
        var result = ""

        while (chars.isNotEmpty() && test(chars.first().toString())) {
            result += chars.removeAt(0)
        }

        string = chars.joinToString("")

        return result
    }

    fun isNullOrEmpty(): Boolean {
        return string.isNullOrEmpty()
    }

    fun isNotEmpty(): Boolean {
        return string.isNotEmpty()
    }

    private fun removeRange(range: IntRange) {
        string = string.removeRange(range)
    }

    operator fun get(i: Int): Char {
        return string[i]
    }
}
```

**Usage example**

```
val line = Line(string)

if (line.isNotEmpty() && line[0].toString() == "(") {
    line.consumeWhile { it == "(" }
    while (line.isNotEmpty() && line[0].toString() != ")") {
        line.consumeWhile { it == " " }
        val key = line.consumeWhile { it != "=" }
        line.consumeWhile { it == "\"" || it == "=" }
        val value = line.consumeWhile { it != "\"" }
        line.consumeWhile { it == "\"" }

        attributes[key] = value
    }

    line.consumeWhile { it == ")" }
}
```

**Obs:** for now will mark as answered, till a better solution comes out

Answer (score 2):

String is immutable in Kotlin & Java, so you can't modify its state anyway.

You should avoiding to makes the wheels repeatedly, there is an existing function [String#dropWhile(Char)](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.text/drop-while.html) in Kotlin. one thing you need to do is **invert** the condition, for example:

```
val result = "--Test".dropWhile { it == '-' }
//  ^---  "Test"
```

Comment: I tried dropWhile but as I mentioned in my update question I need both the updated input string and the output string.

Comment: @norman784 hi, there is no problem. since `dropWhile` return a new `String` instead. it doesn't change your `string` state at all, since `String` is an immutable class as I mentioned. one thing you need to do is reassign the result to the `string`, for example: `string = string.dropWhile{ test(it) }`

Comment: yeah, but sometimes I need also que consumed string also, so this doesn't fit my needs. Regards

Answer (score 0):

In both Java and Kotlin `String` is immutable and you cannot change it after it has been created.

In swift this presumably can be turned off through the `mutating` modifier. However in Kotlin `removeRange(0..i)` creates a new String object which you then discard.

To have it behave as you want you will need to either:

1. Create a wrapper object that contains a string that can be replaced.
2. Return both the split string and the rest as a `Pair`, you can then use the destructuring operators to assign it as `[_, myString] = myString.consumeWhile {}`

Comment: This seems interesting, I've didn't think about that approach, will try it out. Also check my updated question with some further explanation about it.

Comment: Works but the result its a bit ugly, right now you cannot assign the tuple/pair output into existing variables, you need to assign the return value into new variables, i.e.: val string = "Test"; val (_, newString) = string.consumeWhile{...}; val (_, newString2) = newString.consumeWhile{ ... };

Answer (score 0):

Kotlin Strings are immutable and cannot be modified in place. Instead you can create a new String and return it

```
fun String.consumeWhile(test: (String) -> Boolean): String {
    if (isEmpty()) return ""

    val chars = toCharArray().toMutableList()

    while (chars.isNotEmpty() && test(chars.first().toString())) {
        chars.removeAt(0)
        // Do something with the char
    }

    return chars.joinToString(separator = "")
}
```

Additionally, unless I am misunderstanding, your test condition should be `it == "-"` to get the result you want:

```
val myString = "--Test" 
val newString = myString.consumeWhile{ it == "-" }
println("result: $newString")
```

Answer (score 0):

You use

```
myString.consumeWhile{ it != "-" }
```

which stops consuming as soon as it meets the first "-", and thus it's nothing more to do.

The code works as it should, if you use

```
myString.consumeWhile{ it == "-" }
```

you will get the expected output as is correct.

Comment: I tried this way, but I need to update the myString var b/c I'm building a parser, check the updated question